# PHP shell_exec multiple commands with system variables?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am attempting to execute multiple interconnected shell commands via PHP's shell_exec that have variables (part of a system level encryption task) but can't get the output I expect. This is the shell command:

```
text=outputofsomething.bash
echo $(echo -n $text | openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss <etc>)
```

Running this on the command line works fine, running this in shell_exec gives an empty string.

```
$shell_comm = <<<BASH
    text=outputofsomething.bash;echo $(echo -n $text | openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss <etc>)
BASH;
var_dump(shell_exec($shell_comm));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
text=outputofsomething.bash
exec("echo -n $text | openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss <etc> 2>&1", $output, $return);

$complete_output = '';
if (!empty($output)) {
    foreach ($output as $value) {
        $complete_output .= "$value" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo $complete_output;
```

Comment: But how do I include "text=outputofsomething.bash" in what I am executing?

Comment: @Wige: Can you include more example of your present code leading up to the `text=outputofsomething.bash`?